# Can I use a 4 pin molex connector for a desktop fan like this?

Tags: power-supply, desktop, fan, molex

I am wondering if it is safe to leave the extra black and yellow wire disconnected coming from the fan to the power supply, like this image below. I just don't want to damage anything, the fan only has a red and black wire coming from it.

[image]

Comment: Actually your connections are probably incorrect.  The yellow wire (from the PSU) is for +12VDC, and the red wire is for +5VDC.  The typical fan requires 12 volts, not 5 volts as you have it wired.  With such a low voltage the fan could have a problem starting its motor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! They sell adapter just like that, just be sure u have the right wires hooked up. As long as the extra wires are not exposed and properly covered you should be fine